# Cannot open Excel file after addin location changed

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am using Excel 2019 with Windows 10. I have an add-in called Freelensia Macros.xlam stored in:
C:\OneDrive\XJ15 Macros\Live

2 days ago I changed the folder name to:
C:\OneDrive\XJ15 Excel Macros\Live

After this when I open any Excel file that refers to this addin, I receive an error msg that this file could not be found. I had to relink to the right location. But after that thing worked file.

Except for one file Excel Improvement Database.xlsm. There is nothing special about this file. It has many VBA macros just like other XL files that opened successfully. It has some macros that run automatically when the file opens, but many other files have it too.

When I open the file, here are the things I see:

1. The file seems to have its sheets and data intact. But there is msg: `This work contains links...`
   [image]
2. When I click on Update or Don't update, the result is the same. I get `Sorry we couldn't find https://d.docs.live.net/1708..../XJ15 Excel Macros/Live/Freelensia Macros.xlsm`
   Note that this is not the .xlam file. This is another file that I use to generate the .xlam file.

[image]

3. If I click OK, the file crashes.
4. Now I try to open the file in safe mode and repeat. I get the same error results as in 1. 2. and 3.
5. I have gone into Options - Trust Center Settings & disable macros and turn off Trust VBA Object model.
6. Sometimes I would get also this msg before crashing: `There isn't enough memory to complete the action`. I have never seen this msg before. My computer is new and quite powerful.

[image]

7. I used Sublime Text search in multiple files feature to find some useful references. I could not find anything related to .xlsm, but I Found this:

[image]

8. I changed XJ15%20Macros to XJ15%20Excel%20Macros and recompiled the file, but no difference.

Comment: Try open a new workbook (completely new) and drag -> drop your file into this workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the reference to .xlsm file could not be found via Sublime Text text search, it is probably in the VBA module. Deleting the file vbaProject.bin from the extracted files and folders, and recompiling the zip file solves the issue.

Comment: This solves the problem. although I lose all of my VBA code.